# Enable TCP connection on SQLEXPRESS

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Trying to connect to MS SQL server from Java from same PC.

```
url= "jdbc:sqlserver://GOLD\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks";
```

For this reason I have enabled TCP for MS SQL server.

[image]

Firewall is disabled, but I can't even telnet to that port. The same program on another PC with different PC name and same SQL server settings works fine. How to fix that?

Comment: Verify general IP connectivity to the SQL machine from the problem client with PING and TRACERT. Could be a routing issue.

Comment: Trying to connect to the same machine where. Ping works fine.

Comment: I noticed on your screen image that you are on the SQL Server Native Client node instead of the Protocols node under SQL Server Network Configuration (which is for the server). But I expect that is configured correctly for port 1433 since other remote clients can connect.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for "listening on port" messages and verify a listed IP is the same as the one returned by PING. If PING succeeds and TELNET 1433 fails with an error, it must be that the port is blocked along the way from that client. It could also be the good clients are connecting via a different IP if the SQL box has more than one network interface or IP address.